# JQuery Ajax, how do I not repeat my code?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this code:

I want it to do something by default, basically when you view the page, it makes an ajax request and displays all data.

but when you click a link it displays specific data.

But how do I do this without repeating code.

example:

```
    // when click on the link

    $('a').click( function(){

    $.getJSON('file.ext', function( data ){

         //same code

    });

    });

    // when the page is loaded
    $.getJSON('file.ext', function( data ){

         //same code

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your `.getJSON()` call in a function that is called from both locations.

```
// Define function
function getData() {
    $.getJSON('file.ext', function( data ){ ... });
}

// Call on click
$('a').click(function () {
    getData();
});

// Call on load
getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function, write once, use many.

```
$('a').click( function(){
    $.getJSON('file.ext', function( data ){
         customFunction();
    });
});

// when the page is loaded
$.getJSON('file.ext', function( data ){
     customFunction();
});

customFunction = function () {
    //code
};
```